# Video Live Streaming Play Live Streaming on iOS device

Tags: ios, xcode, rtmp, live-streaming

I am using iOS RTMP Library for publishing Video Live Streaming to the server

In order to play that Live Stream on iOS device

I am getting this link
"rtmp://203.105.184.146:1935/live/test11"

But I am unable to play the Video on iOS device using above link
This link is not opening in web Browser
Not able to Play in Simple iOS Media Player

Please help me regarding
How to play the Live streaming video using the above "rtmp" Link

Comment: which RTMP library are you using? Can you post the link?